# Cannot convert Excel file to Pdf file using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, converters

I uing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (this reference i can't find in my Project reference, so i download from internet)

```
 Application app = new Application();
 Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open("D:\\input.xls");
 wb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "D:\\output.pdf");
```

When run to line 3. This line run non stop, unlimit; so all of the codes below line 3 is not run. (My website is hang or not responding).
I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft Office 2016. I don't know the version of Offcie can be effects on convertions.

Comment: To add the reference, go to Project ->Add Reference->COM->Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library. Obviously first remove your downloaded dll. If you can't find that, you have an installation issue which may be the root of the problem.

Comment: Don't use Excel interop in web sites. It will never (as in **NEVER**) work. First of all, you need to have Excel installed on the web sever. Worse, depending on how you write the code, either you'll end up with one running Excel instance for each request unitl you run out of memory, or only the first request will start Excel, leave it open, and cause all other requests to block.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos have free library to convert Excel to PDF, i was used Spire, Gembox but it is limit version.

Comment: @Daniel I was found Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, but it not working too!

Comment: @A.Martial interop is used to *interoperate* with an actual Excel instance - ie an actual running Excel application. You need to install Excel on the server, you can't just use the dll

Comment: I just set up a project and was able to use your code to export a PDF. Things to check: (1) Is Excel installed? (2) Has Excel been opened at least once? (3) Are you able to manually open the workbook and save it as a PDF file? (4) Do you have Excel.exe processes still open from previous runs due to improper cleanup?  || If the answer to all those questions is no we'll go from there.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos. My server has been installed Excel. The version of Offcice must be 2007 to working ?

Comment: @Daniel  (3) Are you able to manually open the workbook and save it as a PDF file? : I want convert with my website. (1),(2), (3) are avialble.

Comment: Are you sure that your copy of Excel is licensed to run on a server?

Comment: No, the Excel 16.0 library would need Microsoft Office 2016.

Comment: @mason: I test on localhost.

Comment: I try using `SaveAs` to CSV it working, but `ExportAsFixedFormat` not working!